# Слайдер с подгрузкой фото из базы

Tags: javascript, jquery, слайдер

Добрый день. Необходимо реализовать слайдер с подгрузкой фото такого вида. [image: слайдер] Активный слайд по центру, а предыдущий/следующий по бокам. Вся соль в том, при нажатии на кнопку "вправо" должно подгружаться следующее фото из базы, а предыдущее удаляться из слайдера, аналогично и с кнопкой "влево". Обычные слайдеры не подходят, т.к. изображений около 30 штук, которые еще и в нормальном качестве, и из-за этого все тупит. И все это дело должно быть цикличным. Прошу направить на путь истинный

Comment: сколько в среднем весят изображения на одном слайде?

Comment: @DogeDev , я их сжал уже до извращения почти, в среднем каждое весит ~ 150 кб, но в купе получается около 4 метров, и соответственно, становится все очень плохо, слайдер даже выстраивается медленно, да и странице тяжко, начал делать свой, чтобы изначально подгружалось слайдов 5, но столкнулся с проблемой. Использую для прокрутки свойство transform: translate, и вот, когда удаляю предыдущий слайд, мой слайдер уезжает вперед на ширину удаленного слайда, и соответственно центральное изображение уже далеко не в центре

Comment: на каких устройствах у вас с 4мб изображений тупить начинает? результаты поиска картинок гугла куда больше траффика дают, и не тормозят ведь? Без кода вам тут вряд ли кто поможет.

Comment: @teran, не нужно ссылаться на век высоких технологий и высокую скорость интернета, она не у всех есть.

Comment: @DaemonHK а я про скорость инета вообще не говорил. я просил про устройства, а не скорость доступа. в данном случае человек вообще скорее всего на локале работает и скорость вообще не при делах.